# React Redux - How to update particular key of a multilevel JSON?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, redux, react-redux

I'm using firebase database and trying to update the value of completed of the key - id1 in the reducer to true.

The structure of data is:

```
todos:{
  main: {
    tasks: {
     id1: {
       task: 'Reveal Batman's true identity',
       completed: false
     },
     id2: {
       task: 'Beat Flash in a sprint',
       completed: false
     }
   }
}
```

My code is:

```
 return { ...state, todos: { 
          ...state.todos, [action.payload.type]: { 
            ...state.todos[action.payload.type], tasks: {
              ...state.todos[action.payload.type].tasks, 
              [action.payload.taskData.uniqueid]: {...action.newData}
            } 
          } 
        }
      }
where 
action.payload.type = 'main',
action.payload.taskData.uniqueid = id1 ( generated dynamically),
and action.newData has the new data to be updated
```

But it's creating a new id undefined and only adding completed = true to it.

How can I only update the completed field and not touch any other data ?

Comment: What exactly does `newData` contain?

Comment: This may just be a typo, but is `action.payload.taskData.uniqueid = id1` referencing an object and not a string?

Comment: It's a firebase hash id.
newData = {task: 'Reveal Batman's true identity',
       completed: true}

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help. The issue was a typo in my actioncreator and had nothing to do with redux. sorry for the troubles.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it figured out!